# Etimologia de "briba"

Tags: etimologia

Briba, no dialeto cearense, significa *lagartixa*. Qual a origem dessa palavra? Há alguma relação com a etimologia das palavras homónimas francesa/inglesa "bribe" (*suborno*) e espanhola "briba" (*malintenção*, *vagabundagem*)?

Comment: O [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/briba) diz que é um sinónimo popular de víbora. É sobre essa palavra que perguntas? Ou sobre uma homónima?

Comment: @Seninha - Tenho uma amiga piauiense que chama lagartixa de "víbora". Não sei se "briba" é uma corruptela de "víbora", mas não é impossível (víbora -> vibra -> bibra -> briba).

Comment: @Luís e Seninha: *bíbora* e *bíbera* eram formas correntes e, parece-me, predominantes, nos séculos XV e XVI. O Camões escreveu *bibora*. Outras palavras que aparecem com *b* em vez de *v* no nordestino popular (*barrer, bassoura*) é também com *b* que aparecem num dicionário do século XVI. Acrescentei à resposta.

Comment: Descobri que a **"briba"** do Espanhol (*malintenção/vagabundagem*) vem de [**"bribia"**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=65lVaIG) (*arte de enganar com bajulações*), que por sua vez veio de **"biblia"** (*bíblia*). Coincidentemente, por aqui também é comum na língua vulgar chamar **bíblia** de **briba**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003) diz que ***briba*** é provavelmente uma modificação popular de ***víbora***, e [Mário Marroquim em *A Língua do Nordeste,* (1934)](http://www.brasiliana.com.br/obras/a-lingua-do-nordeste-pernambuco-e-alagoas) convence-me que foi isso mesmo que aconteceu. Ou melhor, foi provavelmente modificação popular de *bíbora* ou *bíbera*, que eram formas correntes e cultas nos séculos XV e XVI. Dou pormenores mais abaixo. Mas primeiro, *víbora* designa no seu sentido primário, como todos sabem, várias espécies de cobra; mas designa também segundo o Houaiss várias espécies de lagartos do nordeste do Brasil, sendo neste sentido o mesmo que *briba*. Transcrevo o Houaiss:

> **briba** *s. f.* (1913 cf. CF2) **1** HERP design. comum às lagartixas do gén. *Briba*, representadas no Brasil por uma única sp. (*Briba brasiliana*), que ocorre do Piauí a Minas Gerais **2** HERP design. comum a algumas spp. de lagartos da fam. dos cincídeos, e dos anguídeos, que ocorrem no Nordeste do Brasil, de corpo alongado e membros reduzidos; víbora **3** *B infrm* aguardente de cana; cachaça ʘ ETIM lat. cien. gén. *Briba*, prov. corruptela de *víbora*

*Briba* passou a latim científico em 1935, quando o herpetólogo brasileiro Alfrânio Amaral descobriu um nova espécie de lagarto e a batizou de [*briba brasiliana* (Wikipédia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemidactylus_brasilianus). A palavra *briba* já então existia, e [Mário Marroquim em *A Língua do Nordeste* (Brasiliana, série V, vol. XXV, 1934)](http://www.brasiliana.com.br/obras/a-lingua-do-nordeste-pernambuco-e-alagoas) diz explicitamente que *bibra* é uma modificação popular nordestina de *víbora*. Mas mais: ele identifica, entre os muitos fenómenos linguísticos do Nordeste, três que, juntando-os eu, possibilitam a transformação de *víbora* em *briba*; a ordem por que apresento os fenómenos é arbitrária, ele não diz que isto tenha acontecido por qualquer ordem em particular:

- ***víbora* > *bíbora***—*v* inicial passa a *b*; aqui vou citar ([p. 77](http://www.brasiliana.com.br/obras/a-lingua-do-nordeste-pernambuco-e-alagoas/pagina/77); grafia original, negrito meu):

  > Algumas palavras têm o *v* inicial trocado por *b*. A mudança, aliás, vem da formação da lingua: *vesicam* > *bexiga, vagiram* > *bainha, votum* > *bôdo.* Dizem os matutos: *barrer, bassôra béspa* ou *bespra, berruga, **briba,*** por *varrer, vassoura, vespera, verruga, **vibora.***
- ***bíbora* > *bibra***—supressão em palavras esdrúxulas da vogal a seguir à tónica [(p. 43-44)](http://www.brasiliana.com.br/obras/a-lingua-do-nordeste-pernambuco-e-alagoas/pagina/43); ele dá como exemplos precisamente o par *víbora – briba* e ainda *véspera – bespra* ou *bespa* (também aqui o *v* passa a *b*), *Cícero – Cirço* (também aqui o *r* muda de sílaba) e ainda outros;
- ***bibra* > *briba***—mudança do *r* de sílaba [(p. 97)](http://www.brasiliana.com.br/obras/a-lingua-do-nordeste-pernambuco-e-alagoas/pagina/97); ele dá como exemplos *largatixa, bicabornato* e ainda *ciloura, trigue* e *triato*, que eu imagino que seja *ceroula, tigre* e *teatro*. Estes saltos dos *rr* não é exclusivo do falar popular do Nordeste: *bicabornato* é tão comum em Portugal que eu fiquei uns momentos a olhar para a palavra até ver o que se passava com ela (é, obviamente, *bicarbonato*); e encontramos *cangrejo* em vez de *caranguejo* no [*Dicionarium Latino Lusitanicum & vice versa* de Jerónimo Cardoso de 1570](http://purl.pt/14265/3/#/578); o [*Vocabulário Português e Latino* de Raphael Bluteau de 1712](https://books.google.pt/books?id=18VKAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA2-PA137&lpg=RA2-PA137&dq=%22caranguejo%20ou%20cangrejo%22&source=bl&ots=55jPjW1LTY&sig=h75ByCUte-ZSM17fI8xXU33l1WU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiku-iuidzUAhUE1BoKHdDpAy8Q6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=%22caranguejo%20ou%20cangrejo%22&f=false), ainda traz *Caranguejo, ou cangrejo*.

*Bíbora* ou *bíbera* poderá muito bem ter sido a palavra que os primeiros colonos trouxeram de Portugal. Estas eram, a julgar pelo [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/hist-gen/) e o [Google Books](https://www.google.pt/search?q=bibera&num=50&lr=lang_pt&tbs=lr:lang_1pt,sbd:1&tbm=bks&ei=oEstWdOgBYz9adyvqIAF&start=100&sa=N&biw=1366&bih=662&dpr=1), as formas mais correntes nos séculos XV e XVI. O Camões escrevia “bibora” ([aqui](https://books.google.pt/books?id=kCakVnV1mbwC&pg=RA3-PA157&dq=bibora&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiE_pmL6pXUAhUFqxoKHc4nAaY4ZBDoAQjaAjAs#v=onepage&q=bibora&f=false) e [aqui](https://books.google.pt/books?id=nIY5iBVnCCsC&pg=RA2-PA145&dq=bibora&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5-MzVtZfUAhWGWhoKHb4dAsw4ZBDoAQi1AjAn#v=onepage&q=bibora&f=false)). Aliás aparecem na letra *b* do [*Dicionarium Latino Lusitanicum & vice versa* de Jerónimo Cardoso de 1570](http://purl.pt/14265/3/#/5) sete palavras que hoje escrevemos com *v*. Coincidência ou talvez não, cinco dessa palavras correspondem precisamente aos exemplos apresentados na *Língua do Nordeste: barrer* (mais *barredor* e *barredeira*), *barruga* (‘verruga’), *basoura* (‘vassoura’) *béspera* e *bibora*. As outras duas são *bitualha* e *bousear* (‘vozear’). Destas, apenas *vitualha* e *víbora* aparecem também na letra *v*.

Comment: Hmm. Então não tem relação com a palavra "briba"/"bribe" dos outros idiomas, como eu achava que tivesse.

Comment: @Seninha, não encontrei qualquer autor que avançasse essa hipótese, e encontro outros, além dos que citei, que associam *briba* a *víbora*. No norte do Portugal era comum substituir o [v] por [b] na fala (dizia-se por lá, e ainda há quem diga, *barrer* e *bassoura*); pergunto-em se esses bb na fala dos matutos teria sido influência da imigração de Portugal (o grosso foi do norte).

Comment: @Seninha, descobri a "revista brasiliana", que afinal é um livro e não revista. É muito interessante. Incluí mais material na resposta; tou agora convencido que *briba* vem mesmo de *víbora*. Segundo o que o autor diz, muita coisa do falar do Nordeste, de 1934, como possivelmente o *b* por *v*, era simplesmente português popular quinhentista que os primeiros colonos trouxeram de Portugal e se manteve inalterado. E muitas coisas que por lá se dizia, como *home* por *homem* ou *tamém* por *também*, eu ouvi em criança aos meus pais e avós, a 50km a norte de Lisboa!

Comment: No Minho também se ouve *home*, da mesma maneira que se ouve *manino* (menino).

Comment: @Seninha, *b* por *v* é no norte de Portugal (mas o Marroquim diz que no Nordeste é alguns *vv* iniciais; no norte de Portugal era generalizado, *estaba com os pés para a coba*); no resto eu notei mais coisas semelhantes ao sul de Portugal (mas é donde eu sou). Outro exemplo é *ei* passar a *ê*, que em Portugal é típico do sul: *brasilero, quejo* e *mantega* era come se falava onde eu cresci.

Comment: Reparei que este dialeto tem uma rejeição muito grande a proparoxítonas e faz reduções severas neles: víbora > vibra/bibra/briba, árvore > arvre/arbre, número > numro. fôlego > folgo/fogo, abóbora > abobra/abroba, agência > agença.  Só as que terminam em *"-iCo/-iCa"* (onde C é uma consoante) se salvam: ótica, ânimo, ótimo, hábito, mérito... As outras proparoxítonas também aparecem transformadas nestas para se readequarem: fôlego > fôligo, número > númiro, fenômeno > fenômino...

Comment: @Seninha, pois o Mário Marroquim também refere essa supressão da vogal na sílaba seguinte à tónica em palavras proparoxítonas. Em todos os teus exemplos e os exemplos que eu citei dele, o encontro consonantal resultante é sempre dos tradicionais na língua (*br, lg*); bem o *mr* não é. Na aldeia onde eu cresci, 50km a norte de Lisboa, também se dizia *arve* por *árvore* e *numro* por *número*; e agora coisas dessas ouvem-se mesmo na fala norma padrão, por via do cancelamento do *e* átono (mais raramente do *o*) em muitas palavras.